# Multiple conditional color formatting on a cell using IF... IF... ELSE

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, colors, conditional-formatting, multiple-instances

I've got three columns of Names, gender, DoB. Gender column as either "M" or "F" keyed in. DoB column has the date of birth mentioned as dd-MMM

Color formatting of DoB column needs to fulfill the following conditions: 1. If Gender = "M" AND (This Month) then fill the cell with blue color 2. If Gender = "F" AND (This Month) then fill the cell with Pink color 3. If Gender = "M" OR "F" AND (NOT This Month) then fill the cell should not have any color.

I've given a screenshot of how it should look like in the below image, could someone help me on this?

[Here is the updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvpvW.jpg)

Comment: Hmm. Why  does the pink bubble say "this cell is blue" and point to a pink cell?

Comment: @DavidPostill Gender neutrality perhaps.

Comment: The "blue" mentioned in the pink bubble is a typo. It should've read as "Pink".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional formatting with a formula similar to

`=AND(I6="M",NOT(ISBLANK(K6)),MONTH(K6)=MONTH(TODAY()))`

Obviously using your values. Set the condition to stop on true. You don't need to worry about formatting for blank values.

Comment: I've been able to get this to work. But the blank cells either get a Blue or Pink, how do I get rid of this?

Comment: @Holmes Apologies, forgot how Excel handled blank cells with `MONTH()`. Have amended the formula which should now work as intended.

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me! You've made my day! Thanks a ton!